# C/C# Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi Chinese garbled

Tags: c#, c

a.

```
static void onMessage(IntPtr str)
{
   string message = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(str);
    Console.Write(message);
}
```

， its Return Chinese garbled。

b.

```
public static void onMessage(IntPtr str)

    {
        int nAnsiLength = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(str).Length;
        int nUniLength = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(str).Length;
        int nMaxLength = (nAnsiLength > nUniLength) ? nAnsiLength : nUniLength;
        int length = 0;//循环查找字符串的长度
        for (int i = 0; i < nAnsiLength; i++)
        {
            byte[] strbuf1 = new byte[1];
            Marshal.Copy(str + i, strbuf1, 0, 1);
            if (strbuf1[0] == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            length++;
        }

        byte[] strbuf = new byte[length];
        Marshal.Copy(str, strbuf, 0, length);

       string message = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(strbuf);
}
```

， Chinese display, but the length of the string returned。

I need help！

Comment: Who sends you the string? A C function? What is the content of `strbuf`? And the expected string?

Comment: [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public delegate void WriteToConsoleCallback(IntPtr str)‘’                SetRecvDataCallback setRecvDataCallback =
                (SetRecvDataCallback)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(hapi2, typeof(SetRecvDataCallback));
            callback = new WriteToConsoleCallback(onMessage);
            setRecvDataCallback(callback);

Comment: They are functions of non-public libraries... Try giving us the content of `strbuf` (in hex) and of the desidered text (if you know it)

Comment: The problem has been resolved, thank you for sharing

Answer (score 0):

Here there are various codepages that are chinese... Try the one that seems to fit what you expect. I've even simplified the code to copy the `IntPtr` buffer to a `byte[]` buffer.

```
public static void onMessage(IntPtr str) {
    int length = 0;//循环查找字符串的长度

    while (Marshal.ReadByte(str + length) != 0) {
        length++;
    }

    byte[] strbuf = new byte[length];
    Marshal.Copy(str, strbuf, 0, length);

    // Taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding(v=vs.110).aspx
    string message1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(strbuf);
    string message2 = Encoding.GetEncoding(54936).GetString(strbuf);
    string message3 = Encoding.GetEncoding(936).GetString(strbuf);
    string message4 = Encoding.GetEncoding(950).GetString(strbuf);
    string message5 = Encoding.GetEncoding(10002).GetString(strbuf);
    string message6 = Encoding.GetEncoding(10008).GetString(strbuf);
    string message7 = Encoding.GetEncoding(20000).GetString(strbuf);
    string message8 = Encoding.GetEncoding(20002).GetString(strbuf);
    string message9 = Encoding.GetEncoding(20936).GetString(strbuf);
    string message10 = Encoding.GetEncoding(50227).GetString(strbuf);
    string message11 = Encoding.GetEncoding(51936).GetString(strbuf);
    string message12 = Encoding.GetEncoding(52936).GetString(strbuf);
}
```